# Disable Devise confirmable mails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, devise-confirmable

Recently I added the `confirmable` module to my User class. I already have a quite nice mailing system (Sidekiq, Sendgrid...) in my app, so I created my own "confirm account" mail. The problem now is to disable Devise from sending its default email. Is there any way to completely disable the Devise mailing system?

**Added:**

- I want to maintain the `confirmable` module, as I am using its attributes and routes.
- I can't use `skip_confirmation!` because I want the users to confirm their account.
- I just want to disable `Devise` mails.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use the source, Luke:

```
# lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb

# A callback method used to deliver confirmation
# instructions on creation. This can be overriden
# in models to map to a nice sign up e-mail.
def send_on_create_confirmation_instructions
  send_devise_notification(:confirmation_instructions)
end
```

So override this method in your model to do nothing.

Comment: Glad it helped. If you use bundler, you can always look at any gem's source easily with `bundle open <gem>` to take a look around.

Answer (score 8):

Try overriding the following devise method in your model:

```
def confirmation_required?
  !confirmed?
end
```

or use `skip_confirmation!`:

```
user = User.new(params) 
user.skip_confirmation! 
user.save!
```

Comment: This is helpful when importing seed data.

Answer (score 7):

Use skip_confirmation! method before saving any object.

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  @user.skip_confirmation!
  @user.save!
end
```

Comment: I don't want to skip the confirmation. I just want Devise not to send its email, as I am sending my own.

Comment: @CristianPlanasGonzález skip_confirmation! will only skip devise confirmation method not your own confirmation method. Please try this it will work.

Comment: skip_confirmation! sets the confirmed_at attribute to Time.now, basically confirming the user. I'm using all the Devise confirmable module, except the mail.

Comment: You should use `skip_confirmation_notification!`.

Answer (score 2):

I think just removing

```
:confirmable
```

from the user model should do it

or have you tried disabling

```
config/environments/development.rb

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

Comment: I need the confirmable module because I am confirming users. I use the confirm routes that devise provides to me, and also the confirmable attributes of the User class. I just don't want Devise to send a mail, as I want to send my own.

Comment: ah right i see, couldnt you just modify the devise mailer to look how you want it too, seems an effort to not use the built in features?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you

User.skip_reconfirmation!

That is skip confirm mail and update email not to use "confirm!"

Answer (score 0):

remove (`:confirmable`) from devise model
ex:- here my devise model is User
here I used like this.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
     devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,:omniauthable

end
```